# Blackberry signing

Tags: eclipse, blackberry, certificate

I have key files from Blackberry site.

I have imported it using blackberry eclipse plug-in.

I have signed all files.

Now i want to add files to my website so that anyone can download application and use in their mobile device.

I want to know which file i have to upload to my website.

Please reply.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The eclipse plugin automatically generates the deliverables folders, which includes the .cod files and .alx files, you can deploy applications using various ways.
Some of the ways using which you can deploy your application to end users is by:
**1.** uploading your application in the blackberry world
**2.** Using .cod file of your application but it needs the blackberry jde
**3.** Using the .alx file and browsing it using the blackberry desktop software
**4.** The deliverables folder also contain .jad files too, by using this file, we can also deploy applications, but for that you need to follow certain steps
**4.1** Copy the .jad and .cod files into one separate folder(Just to make sure you dont miss any files)
**4.2** Rename the .cod file as .zip file Eg : abc.cod should be renamed as abc.zip
**4.3** Once the .zip is done, we need to extract the files and then copy the extracted files and .jad into another folder(Just to be safe)
**4.4** Now, upload this folder into the website and you hit the link from the blackberry browser and make sure there are no MIME types specified such as .doc, .docx, .xls etc in the servelet and if it is already mentioned then for .jad file mention it as **"text/vnd.sun.j2me.app-descriptor"** 
**4.5** You should actually hit the .jad file in the browser

Anyone doubts please let me know.
Thank you,
Dheeraj Jami

Comment: 4th step is exactly what i wanted. Let me try with this. Thank you very much

Answer (score 1):

You have to generate an **.alx** file using your eclipse plugin. It will show **.cod** files that are used in your app. Upload those **.cod** file into your website.

Again there are other ways to install app in BB device. It depends on the way you use.

Thanks.

Comment: Can you please help me to do this.
How to generate .alx file

Comment: Yes. .alx file has been generated in Derivable folder. Need to upload that also?

Comment: I have uploaded .cod file to website. When I download from simulator i will get error(Invalid cod file). Do I need to download in actual device

Comment: Is it feasible for you to use BB Desktop manager? Because using that, you can easily install app in BB device with .alx file.

Comment: No i want to share this app so that everyone can use.

Comment: Yeah that OK. Create a zip file containing .alx file with required cod file, and make that file downloadable from your website. After downloading, use BB desktop manager to install app in BB device using .alx file.

Comment: Is it possible for blackberry users to download directly into mobile?

Comment: Okey then, either you upload your app to BB app store or use .jad file to install it from browser.(step 4 form @Dheeraj Jami' answer). Different ways to install BB app: http://www.bbgeeks.com/blackberry-guides/blackberry-guide-how-to-install-third-party-applications-onto-your-blackberry-88400/